# Can I withdraw leftover money in PA 529 account because my child received scholarship?

Tags: united-states, withdrawal, 529-plan

My daughter graduated in 2017 with BS degree. She received scholarship money about $100,000 in 4 years. So I took money from 529 only for room and board and so there is left over money in 529. I waited 5 years for her to go for higher studies so I could use the remaining money. But she is not going to study any more.

Now I would like to know if I could withdraw all of my money from 529 which is less than $100,000 without penalty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can withdraw funds without *penalty* up to the amount of tax-free scholarships the beneficiary earned. You will still need to pay tax on *earnings*, though at your marginal income tax rate.

I'm sure your state's 529 plan administrator deals with this all of the time - I would contact them and see how to proceed.

Another option would be to change the beneficiary to someone else who would use it, such as grandchildren or other dependents. You don't even have to wait for college - they can be used to pay tuition at private elementary schools. That might be a better option if you don't need the money now and are in a higher tax bracket that you expect to be in the future.